# jQuery Sortable - using an element's data as the attribute?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to use the `sortable("toArray")` method. However, I don't want to use the default attribute of the element's `id`. I know that I can do something like this:

```
var arr = ("#my_list").sortable("toArray", { attribute: something_else });
```

but I believe this is *not* data values, but rather normal attributes of an element. Instead, I'd like to be able to use some data that I stored within the element itself.

For example, a list item in my `sortable` list might look like this (as viewed with FireBug... sort of, it looks a bit different I guess):

```
<li class="wo-event wo-event-red" style="">Service | Hancock</li>
sch_item="189"
woID="R-130109-072"
woType="R"
title="Service | Hancock"
backgroundColor="red"
pos="3"
rt_item=192
```

So, with the above `<li>` I have data values for `sch_item`, `woID`, `woType`, `title`, `backgroundColor`, `pos`, and `rt_item`. Ideally, I would be able to generate an array using on of these data values so that my array looks like this: `[<sch_item value>, <another sch_item value>]` etc...

Is this possible?

Comment: Your HTML looks wrong - those data values should be within the li tag?

Comment: When I view the code in FireBug, the data values are not within the <li> tag, but sort of stuck onto the end of the element.

Comment: Ok I understand now. You're using `.data()` to store data on the elements and looking at the elements using a plugin like FireQuery. I don't believe it is possible to do what you are asking. You will have to add the data as an explicit `data-*` attribute to the element. E.g. `<li class="wo-event wo-event-red" style="" data-sch_item="189">`

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about this, there is one way to do it. You can create your own iterator.

So, if you wanted to generate a sorted array of `sch_item` every time the list is sorted:

```
$("#my_list").sortable({
   stop: function(event, ui) {
         var arrayOfCustomData = [];
         $(this).find('li').each(function(index, item) {
                 arrayOfCustomData[index] = item.data('sch_item');
         });
         $(this).data('sch_item_sorted',arrayOfCustomData);
   }
});
```

and then you can retrieve the sorted list whenever you want with `$("#mylist").data('sch_item_sorted');`